# R rasterize giving same values for different shape files

Tags: r, r-raster

I am converting some regional shapefile data to rasters using the rasterize function in the raster and terra packages.

However, I have discovered all the rasters end up having the same values as the first dataset. Below is an example using two identical spatial vector polygons, one has data between 1 and 100 and the other between 1000 and 2000. Even if I restart R and only run the rast_d2 generated with geo_dat2 (1000-2000) I get the output of geo_dat1 (1-100). Is there some sort of cache being stored somewhere that I need to clear?

```
library(raster)
library(httr)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)

## download shapefile of NL coropgebied regions
## some geo options: coropgebied, gemeente, provincie, lansdeel
geo_nam <- "coropgebied"

url <- parse_url("https://service.pdok.nl/cbs/gebiedsindelingen/2023/wfs/v1_0")

url$query <- list(service = "WFS",
                  version = "2.0.0",
                  request = "GetFeature",
                  typename = paste0("gebiedsindelingen:", geo_nam, "_gegeneraliseerd"),
                  outputFormat = "application/json")
request <- build_url(url)
  
  # request sf and transform to 4326
  geo_sf <- st_read(request) %>% 
    st_transform(4326)
  
  ## generate desired raster
  r <- raster(nrows=122, ncols=87, xmn=3.15, xmx=7.5, ymn=50.65, ymx=53.7, 
              crs = 4326)
  
  ## crop to extent
  r_crop <- crop(r, geo_sf)

  ## generate some random data for the regions that is significantly different
  ## dat1 is 1-100
  geo_dat1 <- geo_sf %>% 
    mutate(dat = as.numeric(sample(1:100, NROW(geo_sf$statcode)))) %>% 
    select(dat, geometry)
  
  ## dat2 is 1000:2000
  geo_dat2 <- geo_sf %>% 
    mutate(dat = as.numeric(sample(1000:2000, NROW(geo_sf$statcode)))) %>% 
    select(dat, geometry)
  
  ## use raster to rasterize the shape file data
  rast_d1 <- terra::rasterize(geo_dat1, r_crop)
  crs(rast_d1) <- 4326
  
  rast_d2 <- terra::rasterize(geo_dat2, r_crop)
  crs(rast_d2) <- 4326
  
  ## plot both
  plot(rast_d1)
  plot(rast_d2)
  
  ## extract values from raster
  rast_d1@data@max
  rast_d2@data@max
 
  ## however the scale when plotting with mapview is consistent with expected range, the cell values are not.
mapview(rast_d1)  
mapview(rast_d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the variable you want to rasterize. I show that below, with a simplified script that uses "terra".

```
library(terra)
library(httr)

geo_nam <- "coropgebied"
year <- "2021"
url <- parse_url("https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbsgebiedsindelingen/wfs")
url$query <- list(service = "WFS", version = "2.0.0", request = "GetFeature",
             typename = paste0("cbsgebiedsindelingen:cbs_", geo_nam, "_", year, "_gegeneraliseerd"),
             outputFormat = "application/json")
request <- build_url(url)
  
geo <- vect(request) |> project("EPSG:4326")      
r <- rast(geo, res=0.025) 

geo$dat1 <- sample(100, nrow(geo))
geo$dat2 <- 1000 + sample(100, nrow(geo))
  
rd1 <- rasterize(geo, r, "dat1")
rd2 <- rasterize(geo, r, "dat2")
```

Note that while you were calling `terra::rasterize`, you provided a `RasterLayer` argument, in which case the method you are using will be `raster::rasterize`. Also, in your question you refer to shapefiles, but there are no shapefiles (a particular file format) in your example. You have an sf (simple features) object of polygons. I used a SpatVector of polygons.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Robert and also for setting me straight on the terminology. However, why, in my example, if there is no data column specified does it still show data in the output raster? This matches with the spatial vector geo_dat1, even when the spatial vector is geo_dat2.

Comment: With `raster::rasterize`, if you do not specify the variable of interest, all variables are rasterized, and the value you see by default is the index (1:40 in this case) for both data sets. That does not match geo_dat1 either (should have values > 40). See `show(rast_d1)`

Comment: feature request url has changed. Replace with: 
```geo_nam <- "coropgebied"

url <- parse_url("https://service.pdok.nl/cbs/gebiedsindelingen/2023/wfs/v1_0")
url$query <- list(service = "WFS",
                  version = "2.0.0",
                  request = "GetFeature",
                  typename = paste0("gebiedsindelingen:", geo_nam, "_gegeneraliseerd"),
                  outputFormat = "application/json")
request <- build_url(url)```